# Foreign key on split unique columns

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 tables
Vendors
Trucks
Fruits

Truck table has truck # and is foreign Keyed to Vendors with a split uniqueness constraint on both truck and Vendor (different vendors can have the same truck number but no vendor can have 2 trucks the same number)

Fruit tracks shipping history and vendor (has FK to Vendor as well)
I want to add a foreign Key on Fruit to Truck # but I am not sure how to do this

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. 
I was Trying:

```
USE [FruitHistory]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Fruit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Fruit_OnTruck] FOREIGN KEY([TruckNumber],[Vendor])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Trucks] ([TruckNumber],[Vendor])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Fruit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Fruit_OnTruck]
GO
GO
```

But what actually worked was

```
USE [FruitHistory]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Fruit]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Fruit_OnTruck] FOREIGN KEY([Vendor],[TruckNumber])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Trucks] ([Vendor],[TruckNumber])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Fruit] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Fruit_OnTruck]
GO
GO
```

Not Completely sure why but reversing the columns allowed it to be set